# View Controller does not update after receiving data from a segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, updating

iOS Objective-C question: I can't get my View Controller to display values that I've passed in from another View Controller. How can I fix this?

Here's the deal-

I have 4 UILabel properties (planetTitle,planetSubtitle,distanceFromEarth, and distanceFromSun) that behave appropriately whenever I try to change them in the ViewDidLoad method. Example: I tried

`planetTitle.text = @"Test"`

and it worked fine. However, when I try and change these properties' text values within the method I used to receive the data (called cellWasPressed), it doesn't work. I have tested my cellWasPressed method using breakpoints, and all the data is there just fine- I just simply can't change the property values. It's probably something very basic that I've missed, but please let me know where I'm going wrong. My ViewController.m file is below (kind-of haha). (The updateViews method in there was just to try another approach, which also didn't work).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void) cellWasPressed:(Planet *) planet{

   NSString *planetName = planet.planetName;
   NSString *distanceFromSun = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f Million Miles",planet.distanceFromSun];
   NSString *distanceFromEarth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f Million Miles",planet.distanceFromEarth];
   NSString *planetSubtitle = planet.planetDescription;
   [self updateViews:planetName sun:distanceFromSun earth:distanceFromEarth subtitle:planetSubtitle];
}


-(void) updateViews:(NSString *) title sun: (NSString *) sun earth: (NSString *) earth subtitle: (NSString *) subtitle{
   _planetTitle.text = title;
   _planetSubtitle.text = subtitle;
   _distanceFromSun.text = sun;
}
```

Segue: (I've also added the Planet property to the destination's .h file)

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    PlanetInformationViewController *planetInformationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = (UITableViewCell *) sender;

    if([selectedCell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Mars"]){
        planetInformationViewController.Planet = _planetList[0];
        [planetInformationViewController cellWasPressed:_planetList[0]];
    }
    else if ([selectedCell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Earth"]){
        planetInformationViewController.Planet = _planetList[1];
        [planetInformationViewController cellWasPressed:_planetList[1]];
    }
    else if ([selectedCell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Jupiter"]){
        planetInformationViewController.Planet = _planetList[2];
        [planetInformationViewController cellWasPressed:_planetList[2]];
    }

}
```

Comment: the function cell was pressed get called in same class?

Comment: Nope, I'm calling it in my prepareForSegue method in the other controller

Comment: Instead of irrelevant `viewDidLoad` and `didReceiveMemoryWarning` please show the code where `cellWasPressed` is called.

Comment: That's irrelevant since the data has already been received just fine, as already described in the question

Comment: see the following answer

Comment: let me know wheather it worked or not

Comment: It **is** relevant, see my answer.

Comment: why you do not set the Planet instance as an attribute of your target view controller and then do not call the cellWasPressed in your viewDidLoad method?

Comment: @vadian answer is correct way.

Comment: My b then- added the prepareForSegue method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a method in `prepareForSegue` which affects outlets it doesn't work because the outlets aren't connected yet at this moment.

- Create a property in the destination view controller

  ```
  @property Planet *planet;
  ```
- Assign the planet instance to this property in `prepareForSegue`

  ```
  planetInformationViewController.planet = _planetList[x];
  ```

  By the way: Find an index based relationship between the planets and `_planetList` to avoid repetitive code and don't get the name of the planet from the cell (the view). Get it from the data source array (the model).
- Call `[self cellWasPressed]` in `viewWillAppear` and remove the parameter in the method.

  ```
  -(void) cellWasPressed {...
  ```

Comment: Can you explain how to do the last part? I'm trying [self cellWasPressed:] without any luck in ViewWillAppear

Comment: @millz60 i have updated vadian's answer but it will take time to reflect

Comment: got it. Thanks dude much appreciated!

Comment: Just deleted this line- [planetInformationViewController cellWasPressed:_planetList[0]];

Comment: @millz60 so the updated answer is working now.
Thats great to hear

Answer (score -1):

At the end of prepare for segue, add this kind of code.

**Swift**

```
var _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("loadData"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func loadData()
{
    //Call your cell pressed function here.
}
```

This will add little delay to the call.

It worked for me in the similar case.

> UPDATE

**objective-c**

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(loadData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)loadData:(NSTimer*)timer { 
    //Call your cell pressed function here.
}
```

Comment: Any idea on how to use in Obj-C? I haven't experimented with Swift at all yet :/

Comment: yes aggried But dint find any solution for it. at that time